# Polymer- on-tap handler in a non custom element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.2, I have

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <paper-tab name="portfolio" on-tap="bob">
```

This is in index.html, a non custom element.

I have:

```
  <script>
    function bob() {
      page('/portfolio');
    }
  </script>
```

but when I run it I get:

```
`[dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `bob` not defined`
```

Since this is not a custom element, how do I assing the handler bob to `on-tap`?

Comment: I found later a solution and updated my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer/components/">
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-button on-tap="bob">Click Me</paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var t = document.querySelector("#app");
      t.bob = function() {
        console.log("Something Happenend");
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>
```